# How to make a datagridview columns fixed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am new to .net. I will try my best to explain the problem. As you can see in the images the columns are resizing which i dont want to happen. I tried giving `readonly` property but this doesnt work.

[image]

**I dont want this to happen**

[image]

Please also give some suggestions to prevent user from changing the column width.

well this may be a very small issue.

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please comment i will improve my question

Comment: Have yo tried `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Resizable=DataGridViewTriState.False`

Comment: sorry i dont know this. BTW thank you

Comment: At first, I downvoted and edited the question to make it less hard to look at. But then, seeing your comment "Please comment I will improve my question", I understood you. I really understood you. And I admire your attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole set of properties to regulate this exactly.

In code:

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;

dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
```

You will be able to find them in the Properties Window(s) as well. Note the `Columns (Collection) [...]` item.

Comment: is there any way to make the left space(which i have mentioned in first image in red border) to work as a button? I dont know what exactly to say it.

Comment: It's called the RowHeader and you can resize or hide it but clicking it will only select the Row.